# Scroll to Top of page and then hide element using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a div `home` that shown or hidden by a click of `show`. I then have a second div `main` with some text. At the end of the page i have another div `back` which when clicked hides the `main` div. I am trying to achieve the feature such that when `back` is clicked, the page should scroll back to the top of the page and then hide the `main` div. I have the code below but it hides the div first and scrolls up. I want the opposite to happen- Scroll to top and then hide.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#show').click(function() {
      $('.home').toggle();
    });
    $('.back').click(function() {
    $([document.documentElement, document.body]).animate({
            scrollTop: $("#show").offset().top
     });
     $('.main').hide();
       $('.home').show();
});
});
```

```css
.container {
  background: yellow;

}

.home {
  position: relative;
  background: red;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: block;
  z-index: 11;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}

.enter {
  color: black;
}

.main {
  background: green;
  height: auto;
  width: 100vw;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

  <div id="show">Click to Show/ Hide div</div>
  <div class="home">
    <ol>
      <li>India</li>
      <li>US</li>
      <li>UK</li>
      <li>Australia</li>
    </ol>
  </div>

  <div class="main">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Nullam vehicula ipsum a arcu cursus vitae congue. Vitae congue eu consequat ac felis donec et odio pellentesque. Placerat vestibulum
    lectus mauris ultrices eros in cursus turpis massa. Ligula ullamcorper malesuada proin libero nunc consequat. Consectetur lorem donec massa sapien. Nullam ac tortor vitae purus faucibus ornare suspendisse sed. Vel risus commodo viverra maecenas accumsan
    lacus vel facilisis. Amet commodo nulla facilisi nullam vehicula ipsum a arcu cursus. Aliquam ut porttitor leo a diam sollicitudin tempor id. Urna id volutpat lacus laoreet non curabitur. Augue mauris augue neque gravida in fermentum et sollicitudin
    ac. Nulla aliquet porttitor lacus luctus accumsan tortor posuere ac ut. Interdum consectetur libero id faucibus nisl tincidunt eget nullam. roin libero nunc consequat. Consectetur lorem donec massa sapien. Nullam ac tortor vitae purus faucibus ornare
    suspendisse sed. Vel risus commodo viverra maecenas accumsan lacus vel facilisis. Amet commodo nulla facilisi nullam vehicula ipsum a arcu cursus. Aliquam ut porttitor leo a diam sollicitudin tempor id. Urna id volutpat lacus laoreet non curabitur.
    Augue mauris augue neque gravida in fermentum et sollicitudin ac. Nulla aliquet porttitor lacus luctus accumsan tortor posuere ac ut. Interdum consectetur libero id faucibus nisl tincidunt eget nullam.


  </div>

  <div class="back">
    Back to Top
  </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To hide/show the content after the animation, place that logic in the callback argument:

```
$([document.documentElement, document.body]).animate({
  scrollTop: $("#show").offset().top
}, function() {
  $('.main').hide();
  $('.home').show();
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#show').click(function() {
    $('.home').toggle();
  });

  $('.back').click(function() {
    $([document.documentElement, document.body]).animate({
      scrollTop: $("#show").offset().top
    }, 5000, function() {
      $('.main').hide();
      $('.home').show();
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  background: yellow;
}

.home {
  position: relative;
  background: red;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: block;
  z-index: 11;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}

.enter {
  color: black;
}

.main {
  background: green;
  height: auto;
  width: 100vw;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="show">Click to Show/ Hide div</div>
<div class="home">
  <ol>
    <li>India</li>
    <li>US</li>
    <li>UK</li>
    <li>Australia</li>
  </ol>
</div>
<div class="main">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Nullam vehicula ipsum a arcu cursus vitae congue. Vitae congue eu consequat ac felis donec et odio pellentesque. Placerat vestibulum
  lectus mauris ultrices eros in cursus turpis massa. Ligula ullamcorper malesuada proin libero nunc consequat. Consectetur lorem donec massa sapien. Nullam ac tortor vitae purus faucibus ornare suspendisse sed. Vel risus commodo viverra maecenas accumsan
  lacus vel facilisis. Amet commodo nulla facilisi nullam vehicula ipsum a arcu cursus. Aliquam ut porttitor leo a diam sollicitudin tempor id. Urna id volutpat lacus laoreet non curabitur. Augue mauris augue neque gravida in fermentum et sollicitudin
  ac. Nulla aliquet porttitor lacus luctus accumsan tortor posuere ac ut. Interdum consectetur libero id faucibus nisl tincidunt eget nullam. roin libero nunc consequat. Consectetur lorem donec massa sapien. Nullam ac tortor vitae purus faucibus ornare
  suspendisse sed. Vel risus commodo viverra maecenas accumsan lacus vel facilisis. Amet commodo nulla facilisi nullam vehicula ipsum a arcu cursus. Aliquam ut porttitor leo a diam sollicitudin tempor id. Urna id volutpat lacus laoreet non curabitur.
  Augue mauris augue neque gravida in fermentum et sollicitudin ac. Nulla aliquet porttitor lacus luctus accumsan tortor posuere ac ut. Interdum consectetur libero id faucibus nisl tincidunt eget nullam.
</div>
<div class="back">
  Back to Top
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. Could we slow down the scroll?

Comment: Sure. As speed is a function of distance and time, you can just make the animation take longer. In the snippet in the answer I edited it to take 5 seconds by providing a value of `5000` in the second argument. You can change that to whatever you need